# Transactional Data Replication, SQL Server version compatibility

Tags: sql-server, replication

I've been following the Microsoft [Tutorial: Configure replication between two fully connected servers (transactional)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-replicating-data-between-continuously-connected-servers?view=sql-server-ver15). Everything has gone "smooth", however the **'New Subscription Wizard'** is stopping me from creating a subscriber due to compatibility issues between the publisher and subscriber.

#### Error Message

> The selected Subscriber does not satisfy the minimum version compatibility level of the selected publication. (New Subscription Wizard)

#### Versions

The **publisher** and **distributor** are on:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64)   Apr 20 2015 17:29:27   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

The **subscriber** is on:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

### Transactional Replication

The type of data replication I'm attempting to configure is **Transactional** and according to the Microsoft documentation for [Replication Backward Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver15), this should be working fine, but for some reason, the wizard is not playing ball.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way.

Turns out, if your subscriber is a higher SQL version than the publisher this error will always get produced. A way around this is to add the subscription on the Subscriber instance instead of on the Publisher.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use a newer version of SQL Management Studio. My Scenario is: Distributor on SQL Server 2017 pushes to 2019er subscriber. Subscription could not be created with version 17.9.1 but with 18.10 of the SQL Management Studio.

Regards
Benny